# вопрос по recyclerView

Tags: android

Реализовал RecyclerView:
8 групп лиги чемпионов, в каждой по 4 команды и "шапка" - название самой группы (A, B, C...).
Все работает, но хотел бы чтобы при прокручивании списка вниз сверху по-любому присутствовала шапка названия текущей группы и скрывалась при достижении шапки следующей по списку группы (то есть если список немного прокрутили и сверху остались отображаться команды группы, занимаемые 3 и 4 места, а команды 1 и 2 скрыты, шапка данной группы все еще должна отображаться). Какой тут может быть механизм реализации?

Comment: Попробуйте использовать сторонние библиотеки: [sticky-headers-recyclerview](https://github.com/timehop/sticky-headers-recyclerview) или [RecyclerViewUtils](https://github.com/captain-miao/RecyclerViewUtils)

Comment: Моя правка правда была такая плохая, да?

Comment: просто, не в тему, заголовок не при чем...